# Alter column type with non-trivial usage of "using" clause

Tags: postgresql, using, alter-table

Assume we have this table named "mytable":

| name [varchar] | eating_habits [int] |
| --- | --- |
| Anna | 1 |
| Roland | 3 |
| Sepp | 1 |
| Katrin | 2 |
| Lukas | 4 |
| Hedwig | 3 |

Now I realize I want to change the column "eating_habits" to be specific. I create my own enum type:

```
CREATE TYPE diet AS ENUM ('vegetarian', 'vegan', 'omni');
```

What I want is to change the type of the column "eating_habits" to "diet". To do this I also want to map between the types like this

```
1 --> 'vegan'
2 --> 'vegetarian'
rest --> 'omni'
```

How would I go about this? I know that one can use the USING clause like this:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
  ALTER COLUMN eating_habits TYPE diet
  USING (
    <Expression>
  )
```

But I can't figure out what "Expression" should be, and the vast majority of examples online are trivial casts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a CASE expression:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
  ALTER COLUMN eating_habits TYPE diet
  USING ( 
      case eating_habits 
        when 1 then 'vegan'::diet 
        when 2 then 'vegetarian'::diet 
        else 'omni'::diet
      end
  )
```